# Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code given below?

Tags: c

I want to take input from user using structure. So I'm using the code like below. But it's not printing the values which I'm entering. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;        
    };

    struct book b1, b2;
    printf("Enter the Name, Price and Pages of Book 1: ");
    scanf("%c %f %d", &b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages);
    printf("Enter the Name, Price and Pages of Book 2: ");
    scanf("%c %f %d", &b2.name, &b2.price, &b2.pages);
    printf("Here is the data you've entered: \n");
    printf("Name: %c Price: %f Pages: %d\n", b1.name, b1.price, b1.pages);
    printf("Name: %c Price: %f Pages: %d\n", b2.name, b2.price, b2.pages);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm not getting the output as desired. My
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyLSm.png)

Comment: `"%c  ...` --> `" %c  ...`.  Add  space.  Check return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: well for a start you cannot store a name in a single character. Work on that first

Comment: also a huge clue will come from looking at the value returned by scanf, it will tell you if it read the correct data, yours should return 3, are they?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks a lot. I added the space in starting and it returned the perfect output. Can you tell why it is necessary to add a space in start?

Comment: @pm100 Yes I know that I cannot store the name in single char. But as I just started the structure chapter, I don't want to complicate the program so I decided to use single char. Thank You for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is similar to this one: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

And can be corrected like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };
    char buffer[255];

    struct book b1, b2;
    printf("Enter the Name, Price and Pages of Book 1: ");
    scanf(" %c %f %d", &b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages);
    printf("Enter the Name, Price and Pages of Book 2: ");
    scanf(" %c %f %d", &b2.name, &b2.price, &b2.pages);
    printf("Here is the data you've entered: \n");
    printf("Name: %c Price: %f Pages: %d\n", b1.name, b1.price, b1.pages);
    printf("Name: %c Price: %f Pages: %d\n", b2.name, b2.price, b2.pages);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the leading space before the %c input.